# Kelly's theorem about a resolution of the Sylvester–Gallai problem

Tags: co.combinatorics, gt.geometric-topology, complex-geometry

[Kelly's theorem](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02187687) states:

Every finite point set of complex space such that the line joining any two points from this set contains at least one more point from this set (every Sylvester-Gallai configaration) is confined to the plane.

The proof is rather short, however it used rather deep result (Bogomolov–Miyaoka–Yau inequality, more accurately, its   [corollary](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4757-9286-7_7) of F. Hirzebruch).

Are there more simpler proof of Kelly's theorem?

UPD: I have found: https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.0330

Also https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0403023.pdf (thank to Mike Miller).

Comment: There is [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0403023.pdf), which might suit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found: https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.0330

Also https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0403023.pdf (thank to Mike Miller).